# House M.D. - MIDNIT mnemonic

Tags: dialogue, realism, house

In the second episode of the first season of House, Dr. House during a meeting brings up the mnemonic "MIDNIT":

- **M**etabolic
- **I**nflammation
- **D**egenerative
- **N**eoplastic
- **I**nfection
- **T**rauma

Is this a real mnemonic used in medical fields, or one invented for the show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Specifically, kinda.

These mnenomics tend to be individual and can take many forms, they are called [surgical sieves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgical_sieve)

A common [surgical sieve](https://www.mcgov.co.uk/medsieve.php) is **MIDNITE**

- **M**etabolic
- **I**nflammation
- **D**egenerative
- **N**eoplastic
- **I**nfection
- **T**rauma
- and
- **E**nvironmental

<sup>[Source](https://www.mcgov.co.uk/medsieve.php)</sup>

Comment: In the scene, the other doctors instantly knew what he was talking about, so that's why I assumed it was a common mnemonic.

Comment: It might be that MIDNIT is used at that hospital but, as I said, these are individual and varied depending on circumstances.

Comment: my interpretation of the show is that his doctors are recent hires.

Comment: My understanding was that the members of House's team were new hires except Foreman.  I recall several hints that Foreman has been working with House for some time longer than the rest, becoming the second-in-command informally or by position because of this.  He's also given some added autonomy and some work outside of what he does with House.  Perhaps that is because of his relatively unique specialty of neurosurgery than any kind of "rank".

Comment: How long they have been employed is not relevant to the overall question. Is this a "real" mnemonic or not? Yes, it is.